# IMAPClient and BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)] field

Tags: python, imap, imaplib, imapclient

I'm really starting to get the hang of IMAPClient. The code: `'BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)]'` returns

```
From: First Last <first.last@domain.com>
```

I'd really just like it to return the email address like this:

```
first.last@lbox.com
```

Do I need to pass it to a variable first and trim it down or is there another `fetch` modifier I can use?

```
response = server.fetch(messages, ['FLAGS', 'RFC822.SIZE', 'BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)]'])
for msgid, data in response.iteritems():
    print '   ID %d: %d bytes, From: %s flags=%s' % (msgid,
                                            data['RFC822.SIZE'],
                                            data['BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)]'],
                                            data['FLAGS'])
```

Comment: Instead of printing the response how do I turn each one into a string? I tried replacing `print` with `data =` and then doing `data[0]` etc but it didn't work.

Comment: So what is the question now? And why do you have two accounts? ;)

Comment: str() is how you turn anything into a string in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - you can't do that with an IMAP request, if you look at my other post you'll notice something using `parseaddr`, but here it is again with your example:

```
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> a = 'From: First Last <first.last@domain.com>'
>>> parseaddr(a)
('First Last', 'first.last@domain.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

IMAPLIB doesn't parse much of the protocol for you. It's returning the line from the server as is.

You can and should use the parsers in the `email` library to help you out.